# How to split and aggregate days into different month

Tags: postgresql

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dd8d1a1f47ff1e62965ea279bee4cd2b)

run `select *, return_date - pickup_date as total from order_history order by id;` return the following result:

```
id  pickup_date return_date date_ranges             total
1   2020-03-01  2020-03-12  [2020-03-01,2020-04-01) 11
2   2020-03-01  2020-03-22  [2020-03-01,2020-04-01) 21
3   2020-03-11  2020-03-22  [2020-03-01,2020-04-01) 11
4   2020-02-11  2020-03-22  [2020-02-01,2020-03-01) 40
5   2020-01-01  2020-01-22  [2020-01-01,2020-02-01) 21
6   2020-01-01  2020-04-22  [2020-01-01,2020-02-01) 112
```

for example:

```
--id=6. total = 112. 112 = 22+ 31 + 29 + 30
--therefore toal should split: jan2020: 30, feb2020:29, march2020: 31, 2020apr:22.
```

first split then aggregate. aggregate based over range `min(pickup_date), max(return_date)` then tochar cast to 'YYYY-MM'; In this case the aggregate should group by `2020-01`, `2020-02`, `2020-03`,`2020-04`.

but if `pickup_date` in the same month with `return_date` then compuate `return_date - pickup_date` then aggregate/sum the result, group by `to_char(pickup_date,'YYYY-MM')`

Comment: Could someone help with this requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73475658/split-month-days-onto-multiple-row-once-that-row-meet-a-limit-say-each-bucket-l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[step-by-step demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7f8b897183d355f4d29df26593e53fe3)

Not quite perfect, but a sketch:

```
SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG(                                                       -- 4
        LEAST(return_date, gs + interval '1 month - 1 day')          -- 2
        - GREATEST(pickup_date, gs)                                  -- 3
        + interval '1 day'              
    )
FROM order_history,
    generate_series(                                                 -- 1
       date_trunc('month', pickup_date), 
       date_trunc('month', return_date), 
       interval '1 month'
    ) gs
GROUP BY id
```

1. Generate a set of months that are included in the given date range
2. a) Calculate the last day of the month (first of a month + 1 month is first of the next month; minus 1 day is last of the current month). This is the max day for returning in this month. b) if it happened earlier, then take the earler day (`LEAST()`)
3. Same for pickup day. Afterwards calculate the difference of the days kept in one month.
4. Aggregate the values for one month.

**Open questions / Potential enhancements:**

1. You said:

> jan2020: 30, feb2020:29, march2020: 31, 2020apr:22.

Why is JAN given with 30 days? On the other hand you count APR 22 days (1st - 22nd). Following the logic, JAN should be 31, shouldn't it?

If you don't want to count the very first day, then you can change (3.) to

```
GREATEST(pickup_date + interval '1 day', gs)
```

2. There's a problem with day saving time in March (30 days, 23 hours instead of 31 days). This can be faced by some rounding, for example.

Comment: thank you: I was trying to do the same thing with a recursive CTE to create the series and using CASE to find the longest. I've learnt 3 new functions from you `GENERATE_SERIES(start, stop [, interval] )`, `GREATEST()` and `LEAST()`