# Split month days onto multiple row once that row meet a limit (say each bucket limit is 90)

Tags: sql, oracle, split, amazon-redshift, days

Sample Data:

| date1 | date2 | fiscal mon | days diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-10-21 | 29-10-21 | Oct21 | 8 |
| 30-10-21 | 26-11-21 | Nov21 | 28 |
| 27-11-21 | 24-12-21 | Dec21 | 28 |
| 25-12-21 | 28-01-22 | Jan22 | 35 |
| 29-01-22 | 25-02-22 | Feb22 | 28 |
| 26-02-22 | 25-03-22 | Mar22 | 28 |
| 26-03-22 | 29-04-22 | Apr22 | 35 |
| 30-04-22 | 27-05-22 | May22 | 28 |
| 28-05-22 | 24-06-22 | Jun22 | 28 |
| 25-06-22 | 29-07-22 | Jul22 | 35 |
| 30-07-22 | 13-08-22 | Aug22 | 15 |

Required Output:

| Month | Oct21 | Nov21 | Dec21 | Jan22 | Feb22 | Mar22 | Apr22 | May22 | Jun22 | Jul22 | Aug22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bkt90 | 8 | 28 | 28 | 26 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Bkt90-180 |  |  |  | 9 | 28 | 28 | 25 |  |  |  |  |
| Bkt180+ |  |  |  |  |  |  | 10 | 28 | 28 | 35 | 15 |

Comment: I am creating 3 buckets 90, 90-180, 180+ .Based on fiscal mon, days diff data must 
flow to these buckets. Once sum of days in a bucket reaches 90,the remaining days in month moves to other bucket.

Eg oct21 = 8days, nov21 = 28 days (oct and Nov 36days)
dec21 = 28 days (oct +nov + dec (8+28+28=64)days
when jan22 comes (35days), sum becomes (8+28+28+35=99), so we need to adjust jan22 data, we keep 26 in bkt90 (so that that row sum is 90)
and move 9(35-26) into bucket 90-180. and this continue..(pay attention to jan22 and april.

The last bucket keeps everything no limit check of 90.

Comment: In Oracle SQL result set should have fixed columns. So you cannot build dynamically "wide" result set without dynamic SQL

Comment: Thanks Astentx..  But my column set will be having a fixed no of columns, it will be from June21 to Aug22. Since my dataset doesn't have any fiscal month data from jun21 to sept21, these columns will be having blank values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some transformations it could be done like below:

1. Your Sample Data

```sql
WITH 
    tbl_1 AS
        (
            Select To_Date('22-10-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('29-10-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Oct21' "MON",   8 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('30-10-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('26-11-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Nov21' "MON",  28 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('27-11-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('24-12-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Dec21' "MON",  28 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('25-12-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('28-01-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Jan22' "MON",  35 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('29-01-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('25-05-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Feb22' "MON",  28 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('26-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('25-03-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Mar22' "MON",  28 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('26-03-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('29-04-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Apr22' "MON",  35 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('30-04-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('27-05-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'May22' "MON",  28 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('28-05-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('24-06-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Jun22' "MON",  28 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('25-06-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('29-07-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Jul22' "MON",  35 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('30-07-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_1",    To_Date('13-08-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DATE_2",   'Aug22' "MON",  15 "DAY_DIFF" From Dual 
        ),
```

2. First Transformation (CTE transformed)

- 1st grouping (STEP)
- Cumulativ Diff
- Days Diff limitation and over the limits

```sql
    transformed AS
        (
            SELECT  
                DATE_1, 
                DATE_2, 
                MON, 
                DAY_DIFF,
                FLOOR(Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / 90) "STEP",
                Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "CUM_DIFF",
                CASE 
                    WHEN Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) > 180
                    THEN DAY_DIFF - (Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 180) 
                    WHEN Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) > 90
                    THEN DAY_DIFF - (Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 90)
                ELSE 0
                END "DAYS_LIMIT",
                CASE 
                    WHEN Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) > 180
                    THEN Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 180
                    WHEN Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) > 90
                    THEN Sum(DAY_DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 90
                ELSE 0
                END "DAYS_OVER"
            FROM    
                tbl_1
        ),
```

3. Second Transformation (CTE buckets)

```sql
    buckets AS
        (
              SELECT
                  DATE_1 "DATE_1",
                  DATE_2 "DATE_2",
                  MON "MON",
                  DAY_DIFF "DAY_DIFF",
                  CUM_DIFF "CUMM_DIFF",
                  CUM_DIFF * (STEP - FIRST_VALUE(STEP) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) "CUM_DIFF_STEP",
                  STEP "STEP",
                  CASE WHEN DAYS_LIMIT <= 0 THEN DAY_DIFF ELSE DAYS_LIMIT END "DAYS_LIMIT",
                  FIRST_VALUE(STEP) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "CHG",
                  CASE 
                      WHEN CUM_DIFF * (STEP - FIRST_VALUE(STEP) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_1 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) = 0 
                      THEN 0
                  ELSE
                      DAYS_OVER 
                  END "DAYS_OVER"
              FROM
                  transformed
              ORDER BY DATE_1
        ),
```

So far the result is:

```sql
--  DATE_1    DATE_2    MON     DAY_DIFF  CUMM_DIFF CUM_DIFF_STEP       STEP DAYS_LIMIT        CHG  DAYS_OVER
--  --------- --------- ----- ---------- ---------- ------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
--  22-OCT-21 29-OCT-21 Oct21          8          8             0          0          8          0          0 
--  30-OCT-21 26-NOV-21 Nov21         28         36             0          0         28          0          0 
--  27-NOV-21 24-DEC-21 Dec21         28         64             0          0         28          0          0 
--  25-DEC-21 28-JAN-22 Jan22         35         99            99          1         26          0          9 
--  29-JAN-22 25-MAY-22 Feb22         28        127             0          1         28          1          0 
--  26-FEB-22 25-MAR-22 Mar22         28        155             0          1         28          1          0 
--  26-MAR-22 29-APR-22 Apr22         35        190           190          2         25          1         10 
--  30-APR-22 27-MAY-22 May22         28        218             0          2         28          2          0 
--  28-MAY-22 24-JUN-22 Jun22         28        246             0          2         28          2          0 
--  25-JUN-22 29-JUL-22 Jul22         35        281           281          3         35          2        101 
--  30-JUL-22 13-AUG-22 Aug22         15        296             0          3         15          3          0
```

4. Union All to create additional rows for overlapings (CTE buckets_all)

```sql
    buckets_all AS
        (
            SELECT  BKT, MON, DAYS_MON
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        DATE_1 "DATE_1",
                        CASE 
                            WHEN CHG = 0 THEN 'Bkt90'
                            WHEN CHG = 1 THEN 'Bkt180'
                        ELSE
                            'Bkt180+'
                        END "BKT",
                        MON "MON",
                        DAYS_LIMIT "DAYS_MON",
                        CHG "CHG"
                    FROM
                        buckets   
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT
                        DATE_1 "DATE_1",
                        CASE 
                            WHEN CHG = 0 THEN 'Bkt180'
                            WHEN CHG = 1 THEN 'Bkt180+'
                        ELSE
                            'xxx'
                        END "BKT",
                        MON "MON",
                        DAYS_OVER "DAYS_MON",
                        CHG + 1 "CHG"
                    FROM
                        buckets 
                    WHERE
                        DAYS_OVER > 0 And
                        CHG <= 1
                    ORDER BY DATE_1, CHG
                )
        )
```

Now we have the result that we need for final SQL (Pivoting)

```sql
--  BKT     MON     DAYS_MON
--  ------- ----- ----------
--  Bkt90   Oct21          8 
--  Bkt90   Nov21         28 
--  Bkt90   Dec21         28 
--  Bkt90   Jan22         26 
--  Bkt180  Jan22          9 
--  Bkt180  Feb22         28 
--  Bkt180  Mar22         28 
--  Bkt180  Apr22         25 
--  Bkt180+ Apr22         10 
--  Bkt180+ May22         28 
--  Bkt180+ Jun22         28 
--  Bkt180+ Jul22         35 
--  Bkt180+ Aug22         15
```

5. Main SQL Pivoting the data

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    buckets_all
PIVOT
    (
        Max(DAYS_MON)
        FOR MON IN('Oct21' "Oct21", 'Nov21' "Nov21", 'Dec21' "Dec21", 'Jan22' "Jan22", 'Feb22' "Feb22", 'Mar22' "Mar22", 'Apr22' "Apr22", 'May22' "May22", 'Jun22' "Jun22", 'Jul22' "Jul22", 'Aug22' "Aug22")
    )
ORDER BY 
    CASE BKT 
        WHEN 'Bkt90' THEN 0   
        WHEN 'Bkt180' THEN 1  
        WHEN 'Bkt180+' THEN 2
    END
```

R e s u l t

```sql
--  BKT          Oct21      Nov21      Dec21      Jan22      Feb22      Mar22      Apr22      May22      Jun22      Jul22      Aug22
--  ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
--  Bkt90            8         28         28         26                                                                              
--  Bkt180                                            9         28         28         25                                             
--  Bkt180+                                                                           10         28         28         35         15
```